# Calling WINAPI ListView_SetImageList in Qt for faster icon fetching

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I have a `QListView` with a lot of files and their icons. `QIconProvider` fetches the icons via Win API, converts them to `QIcon` via `QPixmap::fromWinHICON()` and then converts them back to HICON. This results in a 200 millisecond delay for every icon. But the worst thing is that QPixmap can't be used in a background thread, so the UI freezes.

That's why I decided to use pure Win API for faster icon fetching.

This is the code I have:

```
SHFILEINFO sfi;

HWND hwnd = listView->winId();
HIMAGELIST imageList = (HIMAGELIST) SHGetFileInfo (TEXT ("c:\\"),
    NULL, &sfi, sizeof (sfi), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_SMALLICON);
if (!ListView_SetImageList(hwnd, imageList, LVSIL_SMALL))
{
    qDebug() << "FAIL";
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I get

> FAIL

in the application output.

How can I use Win API for this? Maybe `QListView` is not translated to Win API's `ListView` but to some other class... I couldn't find that in Qt sources.